# Hyphen character doesn't seem to work in Regex expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I've tried different ways to make the special character '-' work, but it doesn't seem to work when I try to test the regex within the code. The examples I tried were these

```
[^(a-zA-Z0-9\\\\@#$%!.'{}_-~`())]
```

The above one would not work as it searches for characters between '_' to '~'. Then I tried with

```
[^(a-zA-Z0-9\\\\@#$%!.'{}_~`()\\-)]
[^(a-zA-Z0-9-\\\\@#$%!.'{}_~`())]
[^(a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\\\@#$%!.'{}_~`())]
```

None of the above seem to be working if I give '-' in the string to search. The above expressions work when I try to test in [regex tester online](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/).

```
EXTERNAL_USER_INVALID_PATTERN = "[^(a-zA-Z0-9\\\\@#$%!.'{}_~`()\\-)]"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(X.EXTERNAL_USER_INVALID_PATTERN);
if(p.matcher(objectName).find() || objectName.length()> X.EXTERNAL_USER_MAXLENGTH){
    throw new BusinessException("The group name does not conform to specification");
}
```

It always throws the given exception. All the other combinations without '-' seems to be working.

Comment: The `[^(a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\\\@#$%!.'{}_~\`())]` has the right way of escaping regex special chars in a Java string literal. However, it is a negated character class. Did you mean something like `String pat = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\\\@#$%!.'{}_~\`())]"`? What is your pattern supposed to match?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be negated. If the matcher returns TRUE, then it throws the given exception

Comment: You understand you only check if a string contains at least one char that is not the one defined in your sets/ranges? Maybe you need `.matches()` (not `find()`) with `"[^...]+"` regex?

Comment: Does the answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Hyphen characters have special meaning inside character classes. To include it, put it as first or as last character in the class. E.g. `[-A-Z]` or `[^A-Z-]`.